# New liset segment

Tags: steam, warframe

I've returned warframe after couple months, and I'm still trying to get used to the new desing. (The new navigation map and void is just WOW xD)

There are 3 new parts in the list I can't find use. Either can't find em googling (I don't know how to search for it). Cause I dont have enough repo, the parts that does not apear on the screenshots, are the one on the left and right of the "5 ability"

Screenshot

1[image]

Any help apreciated, even a link to the patch notes or something like that (I tried to read em, but I can't find what im looking for)

Comment: What are you showing in the screenshot? And what are the 3 new parts called? Maybe someone can do some more in depth googling.

Comment: The segment that I dont know what is. How can i add it ?

Comment: The other 2 i cant add screen shots cause my rep. On of the has an infestated door, and the other one is empty

Comment: any idea of how to unlock it? Or its still not implemwnted?

Comment: looks like an item that you can craft with the foundry, I checked the warframe wiki on Resources and nothing looks like that, here's the page I looked at : http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Resources

Comment: Yeah, thats why i was surprised. Noone of my clan knows about it either. Maybe some hiden quest on the void?

Comment: The infested door is cannot be opened at the moment, the door on the opposite side of the orbiter is not used as of now. The door in the back of the ship though will be opened once the played finishes the Second dream quest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking at in the screenshot is used in the new prime parts system.  Your void keys will have been replaced with "Void Relics," which have their own, smaller drop tables.  These drop tables are also static, so if something is about to enter the vault, you can farm their specific relics ahead of time.

The liset segment you are looking at is for "refining" segments, which decreases the odds of common loot and increases the odds of rare/uncommon loot.

To get the segment you have to go to the Earth to Mars Junction Node (junctions are new as of U19).  Completing this node and unlocking the junction will reward you with the refining segment.

Edit: The Relics having static drop tables is intended for Relics 2.0, which may or may not be implemented before the Mag Prime Vault Access is finished.  I am not sure in that regard.  Also the community has had a bit of backlash to this idea, since you'd have to farm all new relics for new primes all the time.  Depending on how DE receives the feedback, we may see changes to this.